# Remove the duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

How to remove the duplicate strings in an array. I tried this which doesn't workout.

```
var input = ['john','john','rio','ravi','josva','ravi'];

    let remove = function(){
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i<input.length; i++){
        if(input[i] == input[i]){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    result.push(input[i]);
    console.log(result);
    };
remove();
```

Comment: What's the output you're after?

Comment: `var uniqueNames = [...new Set(input)];`

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code:

```js
var input = ['john','john','rio','ravi','josva','ravi'];
var output = input.filter (function (item, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf (item) == index;
});
console.log (output); // ['john','rio','ravi','josva']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let input = ['john','john','rio','ravi','josva','ravi'];

let remove = function(){
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if (result.indexOf(input[i]) === -1) {
            result.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

You can do it this way also